# Why doesn't choosing different object change Shading nodes?

Tags: materials, shaders, selection-tools

When I choose a different object I don't see the associated nodes in the Shading tab change. I can see the Preview changes but not the nodes, notice the diffuse material is the same:

[image]

[image]

**Q:** What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [pinned you node tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/730/what-does-use-the-pinned-node-tree-do), that means that shader tree is always displayed for that editor regardless of *3D View* selection.

Unpin it from the *Shader Editor* header by clicking the pin icon.
This is useful when comparing materials, if two *Node Editors* are open, or to make sure you are editing a certain material regardless of selection, like say editing a particle material when the emitter is selected, or editing the material when an collection instance is selected.

[image]

Comment: That was it, thanks I appreciate it.